# Can this handling of a null body in Apache Camel be more elegant?

Tags: java, apache-camel, code-cleanup

I'm new to Camel and trying to learn idioms and best practices. I am writing web services which need to handle several different error cases. Here is my error handling and routing:

```
onException(JsonParseException.class).inOut("direct:syntaxError").handled(true);
onException(UnrecognizedPropertyException.class).inOut("direct:syntaxError").handled(true);

// Route service through direct to allow testing.
from("servlet:///service?matchOnUriPrefix=true").inOut("direct:service");
from("direct:service")
    .choice()
        .when(body().isEqualTo(null))
            .inOut("direct:syntaxError")
        .otherwise()
            .unmarshal().json(lJsonLib, AuthorizationParameters.class).inOut("bean:mybean?method=serviceMethod").marshal().json(lJsonLib);
```

As you can see, I have special handling (content based routing) to deal with a request with a null body. Is there a way to handle this more elegantly? I'm writing several services of this type and it seems like they could be much cleaner.

Comment: What does the unmarshalling / json libs throw in the case of an empty body?  Can you catch that with onException?

Comment: Actually it seems like all errors are handled the same, ending up in the syntax error route.  Instead of specifying the class name in onException you have have it be a catch all and go to the same place regardless of what's wrong, no?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use an interceptor, such as interceptFrom with a when, to check for the empty bod, as there is an example of here: http://camel.apache.org/intercept

And then use stop to indicate no further processing:

```
interceptFrom("servlet*").when(body().isNull()).to("direct:syntaxError").stop();
```

Answer (score 8):

Using `body().isNull()` expression in content-based routing to redirect `null` message to [Dead Letter Channel](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/DeadLetterChannel.html) is even more than elegant :) . Please note that message redirected to the DLC will still contain headers so you can easily analyze the reason of delivery failure later on.

```
choice().
   when(body().isNull()).to("jms:deadLetterChannel").
   otherwise().to("jms:regularProcessing").
endChoice();
```

Comment: I'm going to accept Claus's answer above. I like your solution because it handles the problem directly where it is encountered. I'm accepting his because I'm writing many of these routes and would prefer to handle null routing once, in one place.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a bean that checks for null and throws an exception in case of null. So you could handle this case in your exception handling.